# Handle "amp" in URLs from a now removed WordPress plugin

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, url-parameters, amp

i used an amp plugin earlier but then I disabled it. Now variations of leftover amp path leave me with a thousand of "not found" or extra additional URLs with amp parameters.

```
https://www.example.com/post.html?amp
https://www.example.com/post.html?amp=0
https://www.example.com/post.html?amp=1
https://www.example.com/post.html?noamp
https://www.example.com/post.html?noamp=0
https://www.example.com/post.html?noamp=1
https://www.example.com/post.html/amp/
https://www.example.com/post.html/amp
```

Post permalinks is set as `/%postname%.html` ,so post URL is something like this

`https://www.example.com/post.html`

htaccess is using auto-generated one by wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any suggestion on how to handle these URL variations? I'm unsure what to do. I'm thinking to redirect 301 to its permalinks (maybe using htaccess or plugin redirection such as rankmath.) But I'm clueless on how to used regex, maybe someone can share piece of htaccess rule or Rankmath regex rules.

Comment: What are the full "variation" URLs that are causing issues? I would not expect the URLs you've posted (with just an extra URL param) to result in a 404. So what URLs are resulting in "thousand of not found"? What is the corresponding "permalink" structure of these URLs?

Comment: i was afraid of mixing questions..but there's URL that I didn't include since Im not sure if it's parameter or just path `/amp/` `/amp`..you're correct `?amp=`  and  `?param` did not cause 404 error but `/amp/` does..there're created by amp plugin..my apologize if I'm confused you

Comment: You should add that to your question and include the full URL format (and corresponding permalink URL format). Whilst that is a different URL and requires a different regex/condition, it is part of the same problem and could probably be resolved with a single rule. To clarify, is the `.html` extension present on all these URLs and part of your permalink structure?

Comment: MrWhite , I've edited my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to 301 redirect these "amp" URLs back to the permalink in order to preserve SEO and please users.

You can add the following *before* the existing WP code block, ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

```
# Redirect old "amp" URLs back to permalink
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(no)?amp(=[01])?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp/?$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+\.html) /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The above states... for any URL that starts `/<postname>.html` that either contains an *amp* query string as described or the URL-path ends with `/amp/` (or `/amp`) then redirect to `/<postname>.html` only, stripping any query string that might have been present.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the query string (if any) from the redirect response.

This does assume that when `amp` or `noamp` appears in the query string then this is the only URL parameter.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive that already occurs later in the WP code block.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid potential caching issues.

---

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/138764/1243) to the following related question for a more general solution:

- [Redirect AMP Parameter To Its Permalink](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138763/redirect-amp-parameter-to-its-permalink)

Comment: thank you MrWhite..i add the rules on my vhost.conf but it didn't work but its working on my htaccess

Comment: @Rfreel If the rule is added directly in the `<VirtualHost>` config then you need to allow for a slash at the start of the URL-path. I've updated my answer to allow for this. So that it would work in _both_ the vHost and `.htaccess`. (mod_rewrite behaves slightly differently when used in a _server_ context as opposed to a _directory_ context.)

Comment: clear as Crystal ..Thank you very much