# Redirect AMP Parameter To Its Permalink

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-parameters, amp

I have a similar situation as described in

- [Handle "amp" in URLs from a now removed WordPress plugin](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138751/handle-amp-in-urls-from-a-now-removed-wordpress-plugin)

the difference is I don't use custom post permalink `/%postname%.html` but just `/%postname%`, so my post URL looks like this `https://www.example.com/post`.

And problematic URLs added by amp plugin are sitewide (not just *post* URL).

```
Post URL
https://www,example,com/post?amp
https://www,example,com/post?amp=0
https://www,example,com/post?amp=1
https://www,example,com/post?noamp
https://www,example,com/post?noamp=mobile
https://www,example,com/post?noamp=1
https://www,example,com/post/amp/
https://www,example,com/post/amp

Category URL
https://www,example,com/category/123?amp
https://www,example,com/category/123?amp=0
https://www,example,com/category/123?amp=1
https://www,example,com/category/123?noamp
https://www,example,com/category/123?noamp=mobile
https://www,example,com/category/123?noamp=1
https://www,example,com/category/123/amp/
https://www,example,com/category/123/amp

Tag Archieve 
https://www,example,com/tag/123?amp
https://www,example,com/tag/123?amp=0
https://www,example,com/tag/123?amp=1
https://www,example,com/tag/123?noamp
https://www,example,com/tag/123?noamp=mobile
https://www,example,com/tag/123?noamp=1
https://www,example,com/tag/123/amp/
https://www,example,com/tag/123/amp

Paginated and search result variation example
https://www,example,com/tag/123/page/1?amp
https://www,example,com/category/123/page/1?amp
https://www,example,com/page/1?noamp=mobile
https://www,example,com/?q=search_term&amp
```

My `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can `.htaccess` catch all those URL parameters and redirect them to the corresponding permalink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a generalised version of [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/138753/1243) to an [earlier question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138751/handle-amp-in-urls-from-a-now-removed-wordpress-plugin), linked above.

This will remove a trailing `/amp` (or `/amp/`) at the end of any URL-path. It will also remove the `amp` or `noamp` URL parameter in the query string (and its *optional value*) on any URL, preserving all other URL parameters. With keeping this as a single rule, it will remove both a trailing `/amp` in the URL-path and `amp` URL parameter in a single redirect (although that may not actually be required here).

Try the following before the existing WP code block, ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

```
# Redirect old "amp" URLs back to permalink (general version)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(?:no)?amp(?:=[^&]*)?&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp/?$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(/amp/?)?$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^/?(.*?)(/amp/?)?$` matches any URL-path but captures only the part of the URL before `/amp` (or `/amp/`) - if present - at the end of the URL-path. If `/amp` (or `/amp/`) does not appear at the end of the URL-path then the entire URL-path is captured (less the slash prefix if used in a *server* context). This is captured in the `$1` backreference.

The two *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) then check whether either the query string contains the *`amp`* URL parameter OR the URL-path ends with `/amp/`. If the query string contains the *`amp`* URL param then this URL param is removed by capturing the parts of the query string before and after this param in the `%1` and `%2` backreferences respectively - which are used later in the *substitution* string to reconstruct the query string. If the `amp` URL param is not present in the query string then the `%1` and `%2` backreferences are empty and we essentially append an empty query string (which gets removed by Apache when constructing the `Location` header).

This is reliant on a couple of additional features of Apache:

- A stray `&` at the end of the query string is removed before sending the redirect response (in the `Location` header) back to the client. This will occur when the `amp` URL parameter is the last URL param and there are other URL params that precede it. eg. `?q=search_term&amp` is reduced to `?q=search_term&` by the above rule, but Apache itself then removes the trailing `&`, so the end result is actually `?q=search_term`.
- A stray `?` at the end of the URL-path (ie. an empty query string) is also removed.
- Given the above two points... The only edge case in which this "fails" (in a very mild way) is if you received a request for `?&amp` (an arguably malformed query string), where there is no preceding URL parameter, but there is still a URL param delimiter, then this will get reduced to `<url-path>?` - the trailing `?` is still present on the response (and visible in the browser). Given a resulting query string of just `?&`, Apache only removes the trailing `&` (as per the note above) not `&` *and* `?`. If this did ever become a problem then you can [remove a stray `?` (empty query string) with an additional redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33437331/369434).

The `NE` flag is likely to be required (particularly for the last example, ie. `/?q=search_term&amp`) in order to prevent the query string being doubly URL-encoded in the response. The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded, so the `%1` and `%2` backreferences are already %-encoded.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive that already occurs later in the WP code block.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect in order to avoid potential caching issues.

Make sure all (browser) caches are cleared before testing.

Comment: Youre a lifesaver MrWhite, God Bless You

Comment: MrWhite, im getting a redirect loop after adding the rules ..my htaccess is exactly like given above with additional rules added by wp rocket cache for caching purposes

Comment: @AntonNb Please consider asking another question with additional details of the redirect-loop you are seeing and the full contents of the `.htaccess` file. ie. What URLs are being redirected from/to (check the browser dev tools). This rule alone should not trigger a redirect loop unless "something else" is redirecting you back again. Presumably you have already removed all code/plugins that generates these URLs in the first place? You will need to make sure that all caches have been cleared.