# Redirect AMP Parameter To Its Permalink caught in Redirect loop

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-parameters, amp

I have the same issue as mentioned on [Redirect AMP Parameter To Its Permalink](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138763/redirect-amp-parameter-to-its-permalink), the solution given by Mrwhite solved my problem and everything went fine

```
# Redirect old "amp" URLs back to permalink (general version)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(?:no)?amp(?:=[^&]*)?&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp/?$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(/amp/?)?$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

But then I upgraded my MariaDB and PHP version from php74 to php80, I did yum install and made changes to my .confs (mariaDB,PHP and vhost.conf)

but after restarting the service, `htaccess` code stop working (well partially). parameter seems still working correctly but `/amp/` `/amp` ended up in redirect loop

```
Request 
> GET /amp/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http;//www.google.com/bot.html)
Response 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2022 09:46:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 241
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.example.com/amp/
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Expires: Wed, 13 Apr 2022 09:46:52 GMT
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubexamples; preload
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 6fb346ee4f66984f-SJC
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
Request 
> GET /amp/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
Response 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2022 09:46:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 241
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.example.com/amp/
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Expires: Wed, 13 Apr 2022 09:46:52 GMT
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubexamples; preload
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 6fb346efb94c984f-SJC
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
Request 
> GET /amp/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http;//www.google.com/bot.html)
Request failed
```

It seems during upgrading PHP and MariaDB I made changes to my configuration which causing code above stop working but I'm not quite sure which one

Bellow is My configuration

After yum update

```
[root@home ~]# httpd -M

Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
</IfModule>

  <Directory /var/www/html/site1>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
  
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font|css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
  
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
 <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9080"
</If>
</FilesMatch>

 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
     AddHandler php80-fcgi .php
     Action php80-fcgi /cgi-bin/php80.fcgi
     

Redirect 410 /home-marketing
Redirect 410 /search/
Redirect 410 /entertainment


SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/123.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/123.key
SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/origin.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Htaccess

```
# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.11.0.1
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we’re sending far-future expires, we don’t need ETags for static content.
# developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/avif                                  avif
    AddType image/avif-sequence                         avifs
</IfModule>
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest           "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                     "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml           "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml          "access plus 1 hour"
    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                  "access plus 1 week"
    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/avif                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/avif-sequence           "access plus 4 months"
    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component              "access plus 1 month"
    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                 "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# Gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Active compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Force deflate for mangled headers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
# Don’t compress images and other uncompressible content
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g|mp4|webm|webp|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# END WP Rocket

# Redirect old "amp" URLs back to permalink (general version)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(?:no)?amp(?:=[^&]*)?&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp/?$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(/amp/?)?$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#Redirect Wwww https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash
#### Force https;//WWW and remove trailing / from files ####
## Turn on rewrite engine
#RewriteEngine on

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(/amp/?)?$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]
> ```

This is actually a bug in the rule itself (sorry)!

AFAICT this is only an issue with requests for `example.com/amp` (and `/amp/`) - in the root - as per your example. A request for `/<anything>/amp` would be OK (`/amp` is stripped).

This was not actually one of the 28 test cases on the [original question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138763/redirect-amp-parameter-to-its-permalink), where `/amp` always follows a non-empty URL-path (ie. not in the root), so the criteria for that question are arguably still satisfied. (Although this is still obviously a bug.)

Although why you are seemingly only seeing this issue after a server upgrade is a bit of a mystery. (Unless this particular request wasn't actually tested earlier?!)

The reason for the redirect loop when requesting just `/amp` or `/amp/` is that the second capturing group `(/amp/?)?` fails to match since there is no slash prefix (as there is for `/<something>/amp`) and since this is *optional* (because `amp` might be present in the query string instead) `amp` (or `amp/`) is matched by the first capturing group instead (like a regular URL-path), which propagates to the redirected URL and `amp` (or `amp/`) is not removed.

I believe this can be fixed by simply making the second slash (ie. the first slash in the second capturing group `(/amp/?)?`) *optional* also. ie. `(/?amp/?)?`. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(/?amp/?)?$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

---

So, the complete rule becomes:

```
# Redirect old "amp" URLs back to permalink (general version)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(?:no)?amp(?:=[^&]*)?&?(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp/?$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)(/?amp/?)?$ /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

---

**Aside:**

```
# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

These 3 rules are in the wrong place. You currently have these at the very end of your `.htaccess` file. However, they need to go *before* the WordPress front-controller, ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

By placing them at the end (ie. *after* the WP front-controller) they are simply never going to be processed for most requests (except the 2nd rule).

The 2nd rule is not strictly required here, since mod_dir will append the trailing slash to directories as required (I can't see that this behaviour has been disabled in the config you've posted).

Comment: I have no idea why the loop occurs after PHP upgrade..but yea before the upgrade ( using PHP-fpm 74 and stock centos 7) the rule works as expected...only after upgrading I notice URL errors `example.com/amp`.. I thought it was because of the changes that I made on the server. conf...so my server. conf is fine?

Comment: @AntonNb "I notice URL errors" - in your logs? Is it possible users were previously seeing a (server-side?) cached response? And a server upgrade cleared that cache?! No URL "errors", but no redirect either. (?) On a glance through your conf - it looks fine - other than the issues I mentioned above from your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: no, i rarely log into my server...URL errors were reported by WordPress plugins called Broken Link Checker `https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/`