# Mapping category label url into new custom category permalink?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress

I migrated my old blog into WordPress, my old cms has a category URL structure like this one

```
https://www.example.com/search/label/health?m=0?&max-results=8
https://www.example.com/search/label/health?updated-max=2015-03-19T23:13:00-07:00&max-results=20&start=20&by-date=false
https://www.example.com/search/label/health/feed/rss2/
https://www.example.com/search/label/health
https://www.example.com/search/label/health?m=1
```

My new CMS has a category structure (permalink set to " No category base")

```
https://www.example.com/health
https://www.example.com/health/feed
https://www.example.com/health/page/1
```

My htaccess has modified rules for handling amp parameters taken from
[Handle "amp" in URLs from a now removed WordPress plugin](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138751/handle-amp-in-urls-from-a-now-removed-wordpress-plugin)

```
# Redirect ?m=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

# Redirect old "amp" URLs back to permalink
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(no)?amp(=[01])?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp/?$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+\.html) /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

can htaccess catch old category & tags path `/search/label/123456` and redirect them into new url structure `https://www.example.com/123456`

Comment: _Aside:_ Your `# Redirect ?m=` rule only matches when `m=` is the only URL parameter (so it only matches the last example, not the first) - is that the intention?

Comment: `# Redirect ?m=` were taken from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118568/how-do-i-redirect-url-parameter-m-1` ( to catch `?m=0 &?m=1`) ..do you see any problem with the overall htaccess?

Comment: Not a problem as such, just that, as I mentioned above, your existing rule does not match your first example `/search/label/health?m=0?&max-results=8` (I assume that second `?` is a typo?), whereas it perhaps looks like it should. However, that rule is kind of _trumped_ by the new rule in my answer anyway.

Comment: Thankyou MrWhite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect `/search/label/<something>` to `/<something>` (where `<something>` is a single path segment) and remove the query string (if any) then you could do the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^search/label/([^/]+)$ /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

*Aside:* If you are canonicalising the hostname and scheme (ie. HTTPS + www/non-www) then consider redirecting directly to the canonical absolute URL in these external redirects to minimise the number of redirects. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^search/label/([^/+)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```